# i want to retrieve firebase data in listview

Tags: java, android

I wish to retrieve my firebase database data in list view in my `"notes"` Activity. I wrote some code but its not displaying the values.

```
 private void viewAllNotes() {

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notes");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    spinnerData spinnerData = postSnapshot.getValue(spinnerData.class);
                    NotesList.add(spinnerData);
                }

                String [] Notes = new String[NotesList.size()];

                for(int i=0;i<Notes.length;i++){

                    Notes[i] = NotesList.get(i).getName();
                }

                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Notes){

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView myText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                        myText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        return view;
                    }
                };


                listViewNotes.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

My database in firebase is like

```
Spinnerdata ----> -Lnansd3ur3ufbu3bu3 ------> name: tybsc com sci (etc)'
```

I want these in a list view in activity

Comment: here i have also used " String [] notes = {"Notes"}; " the reference is" Notes"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating a ListView with firebase data in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648147/populating-a-listview-with-firebase-data-in-android)

Comment: Can you please show the snapshot of data arrangement in firebase database console.

Comment: i dont really know how to post pictures in comments. im new here